# Moving a UIImageView without using the center property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, touchesmoved

Basically I would just like to touch the image and have it move with my finger across the screen without using theImage.center = touchPosition
   I don't want to have the center snap to my finger. I want to move the image from whatever point I touch.

Comment: So, keep the original point of the 'center' property as a variable, and subtract that from your new location.

Comment: is not an option because the object is centered movement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to handle this, which @richard-j-ross-iii hinted at in a comment, is to save the difference between the view's center and the touch position when the drag starts and then maintain that difference as the drag proceeds.  In your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method save the offset like:

```
_dragOffsetFromCenter = CGSizeMake(touchLocationInImageView.x - centerOfImageView.x, touchLocationInImageView.y - centerOfImageView.y);
```

then in `touchesMoved:withEvent:` you can maintain that same offset like:

```
myImageView.center = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x - _dragOffsetFromCenter.x, touchLocation.y - _dragOffsetFromCenter.y);
```

Comment: how I can calculate touchLocationInImageView?

Comment: The various `touches:*` methods receive an `NSSet` of UITouch objects when they are called by UIKit.  Take one of the touches in that set (if you aren't supporting multi-touch on these views just use `[touches anyObject]` to get the one touch), then `touchLocationInImageView = [theTouch locationInView:myImageView];`

Comment: because for example myImage (100,100) and when touch in left up corner (of myImage) 20,20 then _dragOffsetFromCenter = width (-30) height (-30)

Comment: That should be fine.  In your example, suppose you drag one pixel to the right, to (21,20).  Then the new image view center x will be 21 - (-30) = 51, which is one pixel to the right of the previous center.  That's the result you want, isn't it?

Comment: Actually `[theTouch locationInView:myImageView]` might not work for you because the image view is moving.  The coordinate system changes throughout the drag.  Better to use a consistent coordinate system throughout the drag by (for example) working with the touch positions in the superview of the image view.